# Ejecutar script en background

Tags: javascript, nodejs, pm2

Estoy haciendo un proceso con `nodejs` y necesito que se ejecute digamos a cada hora sin que yo necesite hacer continuamente algo como `node app.js`. El script podría tener por ejemplo un `console.log('ejecutar a cada hora')`. Ahora, estaba pensando hacer:

```
setInterval(function(){
  console.log('ejecutar a cada hora');
}, 3600);
```

y simplemente correrlo con `pm2`, pero no me gusta la idea de usar `setInterval` ¿Alguna solución alternativa?

yo estoy buscando algo como:

```
pm2 app.js --interval 3600
```

No es necesario que sea con `pm2` aunque si sería ideal.

Comment: Que tal algo como el cron en linux que lance un shell script con el comando "node app.js" cada hora?

Comment: @jlvaquero la razón por la que lo planteo con `pm2` es porque integra una `api` con la que puedo acceder a los registros desde el exterior. Esto lo puedo hacer ejecutando `pm2 web` (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#api-health-endpoint) . Es posible hacer esto con `cron`?

Comment: con cron pudieras hacer una llamada a una url con curl

Comment: @Omar algún ejemplo de esto?

Comment: con curl: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11375325/1347215 y con wget: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11375326/1347215

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¿Por qué no usarías `setInterval`? En la [documentación](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/signals-clean-restart/) de pm2 lo utilizan, la única precaución que indican es utilizar `clearInterval` para evitar dejar el proceso colgado.

```
var argParser = require('minimist')

var argv = argParser(process.argv.slice(2))
var period = argv.interval || 3600

var interval = setInterval(function () {
  console.log('ejecutar a cada hora')
}, period)

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  clearInterval(interval)
})
```

Minimist parsea los argumentos para que puedas configurar cada cuanto se ejecuta el proceso.

Comment: El `setInterval` no me parece muy configurable desde el exterior, pero con el `argParser` queda de maravilla.

Comment: Veo dos problemas con tu `process.on('SIGINT', ...)`: 1) no es necesario puesto que el comportamiento por defecto de SIGINT es terminar el proceso, y 2) No se debería llamar a `process.exit` sino dejar que el bucle de eventos termine limpiamente tras `clearInterval`.

Comment: Eso es para que el status code sea 0 (para dejar claro que todo terminó bien) y que pm2 no lo notifique como error, quizás sin el `process.exit` alcanza si el bucle de eventos termina limpiamente.

Comment: @Darkhogg ahí modifiqué la respuesta sacando el process.exit, de forma que si el proceso está corriendo intentaría terminarlo (en los 5 segundos que le da pm2)

Comment: @eloyesp Si defines un manejador de señal, el código de salida es por defecto 0 salvo que llames explícitamente a `process.exit` puesto que el programa termina normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Quizá [monit](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-monit) te podría servir:

Y configuras la tarea de la siguiente manera

```
check program app-js with path "/usr/bin/node /path/de/tu/script.js"
   if status != 0 then alert #verifica que no se este ejecutando
     every "60 * * * *"
```